# How to search matching pair stored in hashmap?

Tags: java, javafx, linkedhashmap

I need to search the matching pair of values stored in a LinkedHashMap.

I tried the following code but its giving the true for any values exist, but I only want that it return true when the corresponding value match with key value.

```
bt2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {   
            if(CheckValueExample.checkRelationship(txtKey.getText(),txtValue.getText())==true)      
                System.out.println("Pair Match");
            else
                System.out.println("No-Pair Match");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Method for matching pairs:

```
public static boolean checkRelationship(String key, String value) {
    HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    // Adding Key and Value pairs to HashMap
    hashmap.put("Bus","Land_Vehicle");
    hashmap.put("SchoolBus","Bus");
    hashmap.put("Truck","Land_Vehicle");
    hashmap.put("Land_Vehicle","Vehicle");

    boolean flag=false;
    if(hashmap.containsKey(key)&&hashmap.containsValue(value))
        flag=true; 
    else
        flag=false;

    return flag;
}
```

Suppose when key entered is "Bus" and value entered is "Land_Vehicle"; only then it should return true.

Any other alternative way to do this is also appreciable, and basically I have to match the pair stored in json file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `hashmap.containsKey(key) && hashmap.get(key).equals(value)` to check the relationship.

It gets the value for `key` if it exists and compares it to the given `value`.

Here is the full method:

```
public static boolean checkRelationship(String key, String value) {
    return hashmap.containsKey(key) && hashmap.get(key).equals(value);
}
```

You should also initialize the `HashMap` only once (e.g. in the `static {}` block) and not every time the method is called.